# Reference a Block not added via Layout

Tags: layout, extensions, blocks, magento-1

I've installed a third party module, and a specific one of it's blocks was not added via the layout file, and was instead just initialised within the template.

I now wish to make a slight layout adjustment to it, so is there a way I can reference this block in my local.xml file, even though it doesn't have a reference name in the same way that a layout enabled blocks does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no.

Changes in `local.xml` are processed during `loadLayout`, if they are instantiating a block from inside a template, this isn't happening until `renderLayout`, which occurs after the fact. Depending on the extension / what you are trying to achieve there may be a way around it, such as rewriting the block to inject the behaviour you want.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm trying to execute a specific action on the block, but I suppose I can do this in a different place; though it will require modification of the module.

Comment: Depending on what the action does, your best bet would probably be to rewrite the block and call it as part of the constructor / whatever method they call in the template. Instantiation of blocks in templates is very annoying in distributed modules, I can't think of a good reason for this to be required (though I'm sure there are some edge cases).